# Why is the product of two numbers generating a decimal that should not be there (only for specific numbers)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, decimal, rounding, multiplication

When I multiply `100*4.6` or `100*4.9`, the code produces `459.99999999999994` and `490.00000000000006`, respectively. It only does this for these specific numbers. When I multiply `100*4.7`, for example, it correctly produces the number `470`.

I tried `parseFloat()` on a whim and it did not help (nor did I expect it to). I do not want to use `Math.round` or `.toFixed()` because, in my full code, I randomly generate the number that gets multiplied by 100, so sometimes it *should* have a decimal. (For example, if the code generates `100 * 3.652`, the answer should be `365.2`, so I do not want to simply round as a band-aid solution.)

Why is this multiplication error happening for these specific numbers?

Javascript:

```
var Product = 100* 4.6;
$(".Product").html(Product);

var Product2 = 100* 4.7;
$(".Product2").html(Product2);

var Product3 = 100* 4.9;
$(".Product3").html(Product3);
```

HTML:

```
<span class="Product"></span>
<br>
<span class="Product2"></span>
<br>
<span class="Product3"></span>
```

JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/2owtz3vq/1/

Comment: Welcome to floating-point arithmetic.

Comment: Because floats cannot represent all values with 100% accuracy

Comment: ^^ ...as implemented by IEEE-754 binary floating point numbers.

Comment: Mmm, okay thank you. I was not aware of this. I glanced through that other question and I'll reading it more thoroughly, but, before this question gets closed out as a duplicate, is there a quick fix for this? Something akin to wrapping with `parseFloat()` perhaps?

Comment: How much precision do you actually need?  If you round to six decimal places (or even twelve), you'll never encounter this problem again, unless, of course, you try to compare two unrounded floating point numbers without an epsilon.

Comment: `var Product = Number(100*4.6).toFixed(2);
$(".Product").html(Product);

var Product2 = Number(100* 4.7).toFixed(2);
$(".Product2").html(Product2);

var Product3 = Number(100* 4.9).toFixed(2);
$(".Product3").html(Product3);` try this one

Comment: Based on the other post, it seems like `var Product2 = 10*100* 4.6;
$(".Product2").html(Product2/10);` will also work (and it seems to work in the JSFiddle). Am I correct that this is another potential solution?